# PHP Not running on specific directories

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian, selinux

Ok. This is a pretty weird error:

I made a folder named '`hello`' at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` with hello.php. Then i created an Alias that told `/hello` would go to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/hello`.
This worked out.

Then i tried to make a VHost, which worked as well:

```
Alias /hello /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/hello
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin noobletadmin@YYYY.com
    DocumentRoot "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/hello"
    ServerName comercial.YYYY.com
    ServerAlias ot.YYYY.com
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3 .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    <Directory /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/hello/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But then i read that `sites-enabled/` was only meant for a SymLink of what is inside `sites-available` so I `mv sites-*e/hello sites-available/hello` and made `a2ensite hello` and that's when all hell broke loose.

Before, PHP worked fine and the "hello" worked out pretty fly - now it's just like there's no PHP there. The PHP's fine since it's a copy of the local files i have. No errors show up.. Anywhere. I tried `/var/log/apache/` and nothing related to any directory that i'm working with spawns.

Also, when moving the file around (yes, i tried different locations), i noticed that my `public_html` has the following permission scheme:

```
drwxrwxr-x.  8 5500 www-data 4096 May  3 12:08 domain1_com
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root     4096 May  2 17:25 _cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root     4096 May 17 14:15 comercial_YYYY_com
drwxrwxr-x.  6 5500 www-data 4096 May  3 11:47 domain2_com
drwxrwxr-x.  6 5500 www-data 4096 May  2 17:25 domain3.pt
drwxr-xr-x   7 5500 www-data 4096 May  3 17:55 orcamento_YYYY_com
drwxrwxr-x.  6 5500 www-data 4096 May 13 18:48 domain4_pt
drwxr-xr-x   3 5500 www-data 4096 May 17 11:40 to_domain5_com
drwxrwxr-x.  8 5500 www-data 4096 May 13 18:03 YYYYY.com
drwxrwxr-x. 19 5500 www-data 4096 May  3 11:20 domain5.com
drwxrwxr-x.  6 5500 www-data 4096 May  2 17:25 domain6.pt
```

But I don't have SELinux on. I know this because the answer to `sestatus` is `-bash: sestatus: command not found` -- I'm on Debian Squeeze -- but php doesn't work on folders that don't have the dot permission (.) (the SELinux thingy).

And, since I don't seem to have SELinux I really don't know how or what happened. (I know, thought, all domains are a copy-pasta from another server i was on)

I'm at loss here. Please shed some light on my path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the wrong way to set-up Apache. Your `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` directories are for **virtual host** configurations only, *not* your website's content files. These should be stored in `/var/www` or a directory of your choice.

Your `AddType` and `DirectoryIndex` directives should be merged into your main Apache configuration at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

Example:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.com`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin myadmin@mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/mydomain.com"
  ServerName mydomain.com
  <Directory /var/www/mydomain.com/>
    Options -Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This file is then sym-linked to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain.com`.

Your website data is then stored in `/var/www/mydomain.com`.

Comment: I know this is not the prettiest (by far!) configuration of "the beast" but i was in a hurry and needed a fast-action thingy. 
For some reason, `mkdir to` and then reuploading the shenanigans again to that new file and editing the Alias worked out. 
But I'll be sure to make it like it's supposed to be - thanks for the heads up.

Comment: No problem, though a "fast action thingy" is no excuse for not using best practices. It's always better to do things properly, for your own knowledge and learning if nothing else.

Comment: To be honest: The fast-action thingy got me to learn how to properly configure a "website" under apache; I'd say it worked out pretty fine after all :P
(But indeed, you are right. Again, thanks for the heads up.) Also: I did comment sites-enabled from the apache2.conf so it wouldn't be loaded as vhost config files -- I'm not that fast thingy.